# Find wrong references in project files with a regex

Tags: .net, regex, powershell, regex-negation

I will find all wrong references to third party assemblies with a PowerShell scripts and a regular expressions.
Each project file contains references like this:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation">
 <HintPath>..\..\..\..\ThirdPartyLibraries\CommonServiceLocator\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

...or this:

```
<Reference Include="FluentValidation">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\Output\Debug\FluentValidation.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

The first entry is correct, but the second entry is wrong.

I've tried to build a regexp that finds all lines the contains the reference to a assembly in a **Output** folder.

This expression works correctly: `^.*(?=Output).*\.dll</HintPath>`

But I think that it's better to find all references that not contains `ThirdPartyLibraries`

But this doesn't work: `^.*(?!ThirdParty).*\.dll</HintPath>`

It finds also the lines that contains `ThirdPartyLibraries` and this isn't correct.

Do you see what is wrong with the regular expression?

Comment: What distinguishes "wrong"?

Comment: **Output\Debug** is not the correct location to reference a ThirdParty assembly in our projects. That's a simple rule for our build process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex matches all hint paths *not* containing `ThirdPartyLibraries`:

```
<HintPath>(?!.*?ThirdPartyLibraries.*$)
```

Comment: Thanks for this fast answer!